# How to post a MWE without personal information?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, mwe

I have a strange behavior with the `microtype` package (for some reason it won't break a word, but no warnings).

What can I do to post a MWE *without* personal informations? If I just replace the text with random Words, this obviously changes the layout and the behavior just disappears.

Comment: Hmmm … Perhaps search for similar words, where you observe the same unwanted behaviour? Sort the letters of the personal information word by word alphabetical?

Comment: blur it or overpaint it on MSpaint?

Comment: this doesn't address the mwe question, but is an approach to figuring out why a word isn't broken.  you can use the command `\showhyphens{thewordyouwantinformationabout}` to find out how (la)tex thinks it can be broken.  if the result doesn't show hyphenation points you can add them either with `\hyphenation{this-is-how-to-break-it}` entries in the preamble or with "discretionary hyphens" (`\-`) in appropriate places.  if hyphenation points are shown, remember that a word that is already hyphenated can't automatically be hyphenated further, and some other tactic is needed.

Comment: If the behavior is not reproducible, there's little people can do in order to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you discover a bug along the lines of: "when I put `someonr` in a section heading, the computer expolodes", it should always be possible to reproduce the bug.

If the problem is in TeX's word-breaking algorithm, then as long as the word to break is not strictly confidentail, you can replace everything else on the line by a properly sized `\rule{10em}{1ex}`. This puts a black box of width `10em` (approx. 25 letters) into the text.

And I honestly can't think of a word in text that would be strictly confidential alone, and I would ever use it. However, if you have such a word that causes problems, then I don't think we can really help you.

Comment: I just did this. Result is this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148626/strange-linebreaks-with-microtype-lualatex

Comment: @someonr Well done and I certainly upvoted it! Even though it's unfortunate, old, and well-known bug, which is quite a pity :(

Comment: Not well known enough ;), I didn't find it while googling (but I also didn't expect a LuaLaTex Bug)